# Jasmine : Spying on a function call of another module

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I have the following code structure :

```
const finalCall = require('./final.js');
function Func(){
  this.process = {
    initCall: function(params, callback){
      let proParams;
      //processing...
      return finalCall(proParams, callback);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to test if my `initCall` function correctly processes the `params` and makes call to `finalCall`. I need to know how do I create a spy on my `finalCall` function, so when it gets called, I can track the `proParams`.
I have tried something like :

```
const func = new Func();
let proParams = null;
spyOn(func.process.initCall, "finalCall").and.callFake(function(pParams, callback){
  proParams = pParams;
});
let params = { };
func.process.initCall(params, null);
expect(func.process.initCall.finalCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(proParams).toEqual('...');
```

I am missing on what object I can access finalCall, or if there is another way to do so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) - it allows to mock modules (require calls)

Comment: Coming from ES6, this was throwing me off because you have a variable named `const` and then use `const` to set the `params` variable. If you're gonna do ES6, do it all the way and use `let` and `const` instead of `var`. Especially if you're going to create a variable called `const`. It's nutty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a workaround to my problem. I created a prototype of the function `finalCall()` in my constructor `Const`, and put a `spyOn` on its object.

**Solution**

Main module:

```
const finalCall = require('./final.js');
function Func(){
  const self = this;
  this.process = {
    initCall: function(params, callback){
      let proParams;
      //processing...
      return self.finalCall(proParams, callback);
    }
  }
}
Func.prototype = finalCall;
```

and in my Spec file:

```
const func = new Func();
let proParams = null;
spyOn(const, finalCall);
let params = { };
func.process.initCall(params, null);
expect(func.finalCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
```